# API Documentation on NGINX server

Tags: json, docker, nginx, openapi

I have a Fastapi running on localhost:8020 and I have access to documentation with:localhost:8020/docs and the openapi.json file is in localhost:8020/openapi.json.

I want to redirect localhost:8020/docs to localhost:8080/docs with nginx. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    upstream docss {
    server 172.17.0.1:8020;
    }


    server {
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    proxy_connect_timeout   600;
    proxy_send_timeout      600;
    proxy_read_timeout      600;
    send_timeout            600;
    client_body_timeout     600;
    listen       8080;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    autoindex off;

    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    location /docs/ {
       proxy_pass http://docss/docs;

    }

    }
}
```

with the above config, when I open localhost:8080/docs/, I receive this error:

> Failed to load API definition. Errors Hide   Fetch error Not Found
> /openapi.json

and in the nginx docker log, I receive this error:

> 172.21.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2022:18:10:35 +0000] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 931 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
>
> 2022/06/23 18:10:36 [error] 23#23: *1 open()
> "/etc/nginx/html/openapi.json" failed (2: No such file or directory),
> client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /openapi.json
> HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer:
> "http://localhost:8080/docs/"
>
> 172.21.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2022:18:10:36 +0000] "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "http://localhost:8080/docs/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
> NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I guess it means that it couldnot find openapi.json at "/etc/nginx/html/openapi.json".

So my question is that how can I import 172.17.0.1:8020/openapi.json which is the upstream connection to "/etc/nginx/html/openapi.json".

This is the command I use to create nginx docker:

```
docker run --link ds-ai-ocr_web_1 --link ds-ai-ocr_api_1 --net ds-ai-ocr_default --name nginx -v c:/Users/ab/Documents/ds-nginx-conf:/etc/nginx -p 8080:8080 -d nginx
```

I guess I should mount openapi.json through this command but it doesn't work like this:

```
 docker run --link ds-ai-ocr_web_1 --link ds-ai-ocr_api_1 --net ds-ai-ocr_default --name nginx -v c:/Users/amd/Documents/ds-nginx-conf:/etc/nginx -v http://172.17.0.1:8020/openapi.json:/etc/nginx/html -p 8080:8080 -d nginx
```

Comment: Could you try to add this clause into your nging.conf:

location /docs/openapi.json {
   proxy_pass http://docss/docs/openapi.json;
}